# Preventing concurrent modification to an object

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I have 2 routes in Apache Camel, MultimapRoute (initializes a Multimap object on the start of the program, based on the results of a database query) and UpdatingRoute (a listener for updates to the database, where the Multimap object is updated when the database is updated).  I would like to ensure that the MultimapRoute runs first and all the changes from the UpdatingRoute are processed in order.  I would also like to ensure that all the concurrency issues are taken care of.

Here is the MultimapRoute class:

```
public class MultimapRoute implements org.apache.camel.Processor {
    static Multimap<String, String> m = new ArrayListMultimap<String, String>();
    static ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock();

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        try {
            l.lock();
            //Query the database and fill out the map initially
        } finally {
            if (l.isHeldByCurrentThread()) l.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the UpdatingRoute class:

```
public class UpdatingRoute implements org.apache.camel.Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        try {
            l.lock();
            //Update the database based on latest event
        } finally {
            if (MultimapRoute.l.isHeldByCurrentThread())
                MultimapRoute.l.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the thread safety, or other, problem is with this approach to multithreading, or how to make the program thread-safe.  But I was told this was not the right way to handle multithreading for this particular application.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: When you were told that this wasn't right was a reason given?

Comment: Not that I understood, but the hint was to use the implementation for "the simplest situation."

Comment: Why do your processors have to touch each other's internal state?  This just looks very wrong.  Given that you're using Camel, I would recommend using message-passing concurrency (i.e., "shared nothing") as opposed to lock-based concurrency.

Comment: Don’t use `if(l.isHeldByCurrentThread())` if you entire program logic relies on the fact that your thread **is** holding the lock. Use `assert l.isHeldByCurrentThread();` followed by an unconditional `l.unlock();`

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you need to communicate somehow between two routes to implement this:

> I would like to ensure that the MultimapRoute runs first and all the changes from the UpdatingRoute are processed in order.

To do this, I recommend using `Condition` based on `ReentrantLock`.

Now, second part of your question:

> I'm not sure what the thread safety, or other, problem is with this approach to multithreading, or how to make the program thread-safe.

First of all, you need to clearly understand what exactly do you mean with your wish to make it thread-safe. My guess - you want to ensure that no thread is able to access the map `m` while some thread successfully started `process()` method (I mean, acquired lock). To do this, try changing the way you access the map. I mean, right now it is ok, but the reference to the map is available outside of these two classes. Here is my suggestion with both ideas implemented:

```
public class MultimapRoute implements org.apache.camel.Processor {
    private static Multimap<String, String> m = new ArrayListMultimap<String, String>();
    private static ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock();
    public static boolean routeFinishedFlag = false;
    public static final Condition multimapRouteFinished = l.newCondition();

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        l.lock();
        try {
            //Query the database and load some data to newData object
            performMapUpdate(newData);
            routeFinishedFlag = true;
            multimapRouteFinished.signal(); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //if we're here, it means someone interrupted the thread that invoked process() method while it was trying to acquire map lock
        } finally {
            l.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void performMapUpdate(Object newData) throws InterruptedException {
        l.lock();
        try {
            //here do some magic with the map and newData object. You may need to change method signature, it is just an illustration of approach
        } finally {
            l.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public class UpdatingRoute implements org.apache.camel.Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        l.lock();
        try {
            while (!routeFinishedFlag) {
                MultimapRoute.multimapRouteFinished.await();
            }
            //Update the database based on latest event - again, I assume you have newObject object
            MultimapRoute.performMapUpdate(newData);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //if we're here, it means someone interrupted the thread that invoked process() method while it was waiting for condition or trying to acquire map lock
        } finally {
             l.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do never use `Condition` without an actual check for the real condition. At least another `boolean` variable is required for this. Read the documentation of `Condition` and think about what happens if either, `await` is called *after* `signal` has been called or if a “spurious wakeup” occurred.

Comment: @Holger Makes sense. Wakeup will trigger execution too early. Will update the code. BTW, what will happen if `await` is called after `signal`? I have no answer better then "it will never wakeup" (not considering spurious wakeups).

Comment: “it might wait forever” is indeed the right answer. That’s why you have to check the flag in a pre-test loop. Note that `await` and `signal` can only be called on a `Condition` while the associated `Lock` is held. Therefore, the `boolean` flag does not need to be declared `volatile`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, for some reason I didn't thought about lock acquire. Will think about H-B edges and will remove volatile as soon as I manage to get a clear picture)

Comment: Updated the code. Fixed `IllegalMonitorStateException` on `await/signal`, removed `volatile` modifier - it is redundant as lock release *happens-before* this lock can be acquired by another thread, thus making ` = true` *happens-before* `true` can be read from variable by another thread. Many thanks to @Holger once again.

Comment: A last little remark. If `lock()` fails, you should not invoke `unlock()`, hence, `lock()` should be placed *before* the `try … finally …` block. Compare to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html